Real time kernel for Nvidia and WSL2
I am trying to set up a real time kernel (Preempt_RT) for a Franka Emika robot. My computer is running on Nvidia, and I have read that Nvidia and Linux RT don't go together. In addition, I am using Window Subsystem for Linux WSL2.
Here is my uname -r output:
root@ece-cdw-ts10:~# uname -r
5.10.16.3-microsoft-standard-WSL2


I tried:
curl -SLO https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v5.x/linux-5.10.16.tar.xz
curl -SLO https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v5.x/linux-5.10.16.tar.sign
curl -SLO https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/rt/5.10/patch-5.10.16-rt30.patch.xz
curl -SLO https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/rt/5.10/patch-5.10.16-rt30.patch.sign

but it doesn't run.

What system are you using??  as your details highlight a 5.10 kernel which is not used by Ubuntu (only Ubuntu based systems like provided by Nvidia which uses Debian 5.10 kernels).  What OS/release are you using?  Was it from Ubuntu? or from Nvidia?

Hi. I am using Windows 11 WSL2 with Ubuntu 20.04.06 LTS system and ROS Noetic Ninjemys. I am following the tutorial https://frankaemika.github.io/docs/installation_linux.html to set up the real time kernel, but I believe it is because my computer is running on Nvidia which is not supported by Linux RT that is causing issue?

Real time kernel won't work in a VM/WSL2. The real time kernel OS must be the primary OS. The reason why nVIDIA graphics card often don't work with an RT kernel is because nVIDIA uses already custom kernels which mostly are not RT kernels. If you have enough knowledge, you could compile your own RT kernel with nVIDIA support, but nobody will give you an easy answer, as its not an easy task.

Thanks! Does that also applies to Ubuntu 24.04? It seems like Ubuntu 24.04 is a newer version that should works with Nvidia? Would that also require own compilation of RT kernel?

I would highly recommend using a mini PC (Intel NUC, Jetson Nano or actually Franka's AI Companion developed for this exact purpose!) between the Franka Robot master controller and your workstation PC with the NVIDIA Graphics Card. I've used this setup for a while now (with a basic NVIDIA Jetson Nano in my case) and it made my life much easier.
